# For smooth plane cubic over $\mathbb{Q}$, quadratic point implies rational point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to prove that, if $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$ is a smooth plane cubic defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a quadratic number field, then $C(K) \ne \emptyset \implies C(\mathbb{Q}) \ne \emptyset$.

My idea was as follows:

- Suppose $P \in C(K)$, and so in particular $C$ is an elliptic curve over $K$. Since is $C$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, if $P \in C(K)$ then the Galois-conjugate point $\bar{P} \in C(K)$ also.
- Let $L$ be the line through $P$ and $\bar{P}$, which is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ since the midpoint and gradient are rational. The elliptic curve group law gives $P + \bar{P} + Q = 0$, and since $C(K)$ is a subgroup, we have that $Q \in C(K)$ also.
- Since $L$ and $C$ both defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $Q \in L \cap C \implies \bar{Q} \in L \cap C$, and so $Q \in \{P, \bar{P}, Q\}$. To conclude we consider what happens in each case:

  - If $\bar{Q} = Q$ then $Q$ is rational, done.
  - Otherwise, say $Q = P$ wlog, then $P$ intersects $L$ with multiplicity 2. But then considering the Galois action, so does $\bar{P}$. This contradicts Bezout.

My questions are:

- Is the proof above correct? I'm fairly new to algebraic/projective geometry so not particularly confident in my reasoning.
- Is there a standard proof? I would like to generalise this for degree $n$ extensions for larger $n$. But this approach, even if valid, seems heavily specific to quadratic extensions.

Thank you!